# Get a value from a JSP page to Java Class

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a drop down in JSP Page and I am selecting value of a country Code from this page. I want to fetch this Country Code in other Class where I can use it to get states list corresponding to the selected Country.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
<body>

<button id="mybtn">Get Country</button>

<div>
<select id="output">

<script type="text/javascript">

                                         $('#mybtn').click(function () {

                                            $.getJSON('countryDetail', function (data) {
                                                $("select#output > option").remove();
                                                 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                                                    $("#output").append('<option>' + value['countryCode'] + " " + value['countryName']   + '</option>');

                                                    $("select").change(function(){
                                                        var selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                                                        document.getElementById("Country").innerHTML = selectedOption;
                                                       
                                                                                                             
                                                            var countryDetails= document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
                                                           
                                                        
                                                    });
                                                  
                                                    
                                                });
                                            });
                                        }); 

                                         
</script>


</select>


<h1>"The value for Country is: " <span id="Country"></span></h1>



</body>
</html>
```

*The Java class where I want to fetch the Country Code and use the value in query  is:*

```
@Repository
public class StateDetailDAOImpl implements StateDetailDAO {
    
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    


    @Override
    public List<StateDetail> getStateDetail() {
        
        
        
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        
        Query<StateDetail> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from StateDetail", StateDetail.class);

        List<StateDetail> StateDetails = theQuery.getResultList();


        return stateDetails;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using servlet ? How you are getting value which is passed through ajax ?

Comment: I am using a controller  to get list of Country

Comment: So does select-box gets populated ? Also `$("select").change(function(){..` this should be outside click handler.Currently what doesn't work ?

Comment: This select $("select").change(function(){.. is working.  I just want to fetch the value of value['countryCode']  into the Java Class  StateDetailDAOImpl, so that I can use the value of selected 'countryCode' in my Hibernate Query.